# Replicating an Animation with Particles.JS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, particles

I'm trying to replicate the animation effect of the particles exploding forward upon the load of this page: http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="particles-js">
    <canvas class="particles-js-canvas-el">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function () {
      console.log('particles.json loaded...');
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background position: 50% 50%;
  left: 0px;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#particles-js .particles-js-canvas-el {
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: appear 1.4s 1;
  animation: appear 1.4s 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not getting any animated response.

I would appreciate any insight into this matter! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it doesn't work:

You don't see the animation is because you have not defined its frames.

The demo has this CSS

```
#particles-js .particles-js-canvas-el {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: appear 1.4s 1;
    animation: appear 1.4s 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Which is great but won't do anything without the actual animation frames. The animation frames are later defined in the sheet like so (example):

```
@keyframes appear {
 0% {
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
}
  100% {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

**You can try and see if adding the above to your CSS work. If so, great, if not create your own like below**

---

### How to do it from scratch

You can use CSS animation on either `#particles-js` or the canvas inside it.

Set  to `transform: scale(0)` and  by default and then using [css animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), bring back the scale from `0` to `1`

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mq39h8L/3/)

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden
}

#particles-js {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background position: 50% 50%;
  left: 0px;
  animation: explode 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

@keyframes explode {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js">
```

To apply the animation to the particles only, you need to apply the animation to the `<canvas>` element. With your current code, adding the CSS below would be enough because everything else is set up.

```
#particles-js .particles-js-canvas-el {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: explode 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes explode {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome; this definitely works bring the div into existence! However, would you happen to know how I could just apply this to the nodes themselves? Right now, the entire black box is exploding in :p

Comment: Yeah, the box or `#particles-js` has the background you'll want to apply it to the canvas then. on the demo website the canvas is identified as `<canvas class="particles-js-canvas-el"  ...  "></canvas>` set up a live demo with your code and I'd be happy to look at it

Comment: @I haz kode Okay so I tried to set up the live demo, failed miserably, BUT got the canvas thing working. It works. However, I was wondering if there's a more "majestic" way of doing the explosion versus the keyframe from/to? Like something that would make it look a little less jarred towards the end of the animation.

Comment: @I haz kode Also, upon inspecting element of the source on the website I linked above, I noticed he did this:

`-ms-transform: scale(1);`
`-webkit-transform: scale(1);`
`transform: scale(1);`
`opacity: 1;`
`-webkit-animation: appear 1.4s 1;`
`animation: appear 1.4s 1;`
`-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;`
`animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

Yet it doesn't when I try. Is there some reason I can't get the animations working this way? In his source, there doesn't appear to be any other code related to the animations.

Comment: @Rohan I updated the answer with more details. As for your question about a more majestic animation, yes, there are many ways you can animate it. I need to see an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @I haz kode Thanks so much man, it works perfectly. Just for future reference, I couldn't find the `@keyframes appear {` when I searched through the source. Where did you find it, so that I know for later projects?

Comment: @Rohan if you need to see what frames are defined in any animation then open the dev tools, select the element that has the animation, and scroll down all the way. The keyframe definitions are *usually* last thing towards the bottom. Let me know if you need anything else.